# Excel freeze a specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I wanted to freeze only the S column in the excel sheet. Not from A-S, Just the S column when I scroll past it. Is there a way for that. Tried searching online but couldn't find any solution.
The freeze pane option is freezing all the columns from A to S.
Please let me know.

Comment: May be not possible.

Comment: I don't think there is a freeze pane for "mid" columns/rows. You might use [split panes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-panes-to-lock-rows-or-columns-in-separate-worksheet-areas-516a7001-b3ed-4122-a6bb-fd6d4a9d6434?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your sheet module to automatically apply/remove a [split](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-panes-to-lock-rows-or-columns-in-separate-worksheet-areas-516a7001-b3ed-4122-a6bb-fd6d4a9d6434?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to your window:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngSplit As Range
    
    'Setting.
    Set RngSplit = Me.Range("S:S")
    
    'Focusing ActiveWindow.
    With ActiveWindow
        'Checking if ActiveWindow is already split.
        If .Panes.Count = 1 Then
            'Checking if the first visible column on the left is to the left of RngSplit column.
            If .ScrollColumn > RngSplit.Column Then
                'Splitting the ActiveWindow.
                .SplitColumn = 1
                .Panes(1).ScrollColumn = RngSplit.Column
            End If
        Else
            'Checking if the first visible column on the left in the second pane is to the right of or the actual RngSplit column.
            If .Panes(2).ScrollColumn <= RngSplit.Column Then
                'Unsplitting the ActiveWindow.
                .Split = False
            End If
        End If
    End With
        
End Sub
```

It will activate whenever you change your selection.